# Storing configuration in database

Tags: database, web-applications, configuration, web-config, kohana

I'm having a problem with my application configuration. It's based on KohanaPHP framework, currently I store configuration in custom config file:

```
$config['status'] = array(
    '1' => 5,
    '2' => 10,
    '3' => 15,
    '4' => 20,
    '5' => 25,
    '6' => 30
);
```

and then in view/controller (when needed):

```
$arr = Kohana::config('settings.status'); echo $arr[$item->status]
```

Now I'm looking for the best method to store such config arrays in database.

What would you recommend? Separate tables? Putting everything in one table? Would you give me a tip?

Cheers,
M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kohana already has a database configuration reader/writer:

```
// In bootstrap.php
Kohana::$config->attach(new Kohana_Config_Database);
```

The class `Kohana_Config_Database` is in the database module.

Comment: Great! Thanks! If you can take a lot at this question it would be awesome: stackoverflow.com/questions/5022879/orm-relation-caching. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on how similar/different these arrays are. Normally, I'd say you create separate tables with an Id, Value and potentially a sort order. You'd create a separate table for each of these, because these arrays are unrelated even though they may have the same structure.

However, I cannot tell by far what this array of yours does. Maybe it's better to just leave it in the config file, unless you want to refer to it from other database records.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Basically they are the same type of arrays however I'm creating an admin control panel right now and decided that will be more flexible to store them in db rather than editing config file every time I need to change something. Few of these arrays will be modified very often so I think it might be a good choice to put them in database. What do you think?